# jquery autocomplete source without url

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to provide source to jquery autocomplete the result which i get from the change event of another select tag. my ajax call is return the json array fine but i am doing something wrong here which i am unable to fix please look at the code below

```
jQuery("#city").change(function(){
    var city = jQuery("#city").val()
    jQuery.ajax({
        async: false,
        global: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://example.com/wp-content/themes/abc/areas-ajax.php',
        data: {city: city},
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            var areas = response;
                jQuery( "#area" ).autocomplete({
                source: areas
            });
        }
    });
```

As soon as i type in the input box it makes a get request which it should not in my scenario as i am providing source within the script.

Comment: Try areas = JSON.parse(response);

Comment: what is the response of ajax call?

Comment: ["F.b Area","Gulberg","Gulshan-e-Iqbal"]  this response

Comment: @EvadeCaptcha dude you rock

Comment: @EvadeCaptcha can you answer me so that i can accept and upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to parse the json response for it to be understood by jQuery:

```
 var areas = JSON.parse(response);
```